# Which is more efficient preemptive or nonpreemptive scheduler?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, theory, scheduler, preemptive

I am just learning about preemptive and nonpreemptive schedulers so I was wondering which is more efficient a preemptive or nonpreemptive scheduler? or are they equally efficient? or are they just specialized for one task and are efficient in there own way?

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-preemtive scheduler if you want I/O and inter-thread comms to be slower than Ruby running on an abacus.

Use a preemptive scheduler if you want to be saddled with locks, queues, mutexes and semaphores.

[I've also heard that there are positive characteristics too, but you'll have to Google for that, since googling your exact title results in: 'About 55,900 results']